# Jump to specific line in .txt file where all lines are of equal length in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file which contains about 1 million lines of information. I'm looking for a way to jump to a specific line given that I know which line I want, and all lines are of equal length.

I read that it's possible to do so without having to read each line given that all lines are equal. If so, can anyone provide an example code of how do I do this? Or am I better off simply reading each line and looping it?

Comment: If you know the line length in bytes, you can use a `SeekableByteChannel`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for a random file access

```
File file = ...;
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
int lineNumber = ...; // first line number is 0
int lineWidth = ...;  // your fixed line width
long beginIndexOfLine = lineWidth * lineNumber;
randomAccessFile.seek(beginIndexOfLine);

byte[] line = new byte[lineWidth];
randomAccessFile.read(line);
```

Comment: Pointer to seek in `RandomAccessFile = lineWidth * lineNumber` only if lines (text) are single byte characters, otherwise, we have to account for character encoding in `char -> bytes` conversion.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm looking for something like this. But how do I check my line width? Is it based on the number of charcters or bytes per line? I'm using ASCII encoding.

Comment: @ChrystleSoh since, all your lines are same width, just read first line (using e.g. a `BufferedReader`) and convert to byte length `(string.getBytes("char encoding").length)` and store it as a constant somewhere.

Comment: @BimaleshJha Of course... If the a "line" has not a fixed byte width - it will not work. But than we can not use random access since it is based on bytes.

Comment: If you have to use a special encoding you should choose the fixed byte length per line so that it can hold the worst case of encoded bytes. This also means that you will have a lot of unused space in most of the lines, but that is the price to pay if you want random access with an encoding that can consume more than 2 bytes for a character.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
String line = FileUtils.readLines(file).get(lineNumber);
```

or you may try using iterator like this:-

```
LineIterator l= IOUtils.lineIterator(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")));
 for (int lineNumber = 0; l.hasNext(); lineNumber++) {
    String line = (String) l.next();
    if (lineNumber == desiredLineNumber) {
        return line;
    }
 }
```

EDIT:-

From [here](http://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/how-to-read-a-specific-line-from-a-very-large-file-in-java/):-

```
int sizeofrecordinbytes = 290;
 // for this example this is 1 based, not zero based 
int recordIWantToStartAt = 12400;
int totalRecordsIWant = 1000;

File myfile = new File("someGiantFile.txt");


// where to seek to
long seekToByte =  (recordIWantToStartAt == 1 ? 0 : ((recordIWantToStartAt-1) * sizeofrecordinbytes));

// byte the reader will jump to once we know where to go
long startAtByte = 0;

// seek to that position using a RandomAccessFile
try {
        // NOTE since we are using fixed length records, you could actually skip this 
        // and just use our seekToByte as the value for the BufferedReader.skip() call below

    RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile(myfile,"r");
    rand.seek(seekToByte);
    startAtByte = rand.getFilePointer();
    rand.close();

} catch(IOException e) {
    // do something
}

// Do it using the BufferedReader 
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    // lets fire up a buffered reader and skip right to that spot.
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myfile));
    reader.skip(startAtByte);

    String line;
    long totalRead = 0;
    char[] buffer = new char[sizeofrecordinbytes];
    while(totalRead < totalRecordsIWant && (-1 != reader.read(buffer, 0, sizeofrecordinbytes))) {
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
        totalRead++;
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle this

} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {reader.close();} catch(Exception ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeroenVannevel:- Yes but I have given the first solution if OP knows the line numbers then we can use String line = FileUtils.readLines(file).get(lineNumber); (Do correct me if I am wrong!!)

Comment: I agree that it's a convenient method, but it will still read every line of the file first (which is contrary to what the OP requested).

Comment: @RahulTripathi FileUtils would read line by line and discard till it gets to the target line. Still, it will read all preceding lines. Not the solution OP is asking. He wants a random access to any line, but, fileUtils internally uses a stream based processing.

Comment: @BimaleshJha:- Updated the answer which OP is looking for. Hope that makes sense now!!